# Export windows customized settings

Tags: windows, backup, export

Got tired of customizing things all over everytime I have to wipe windows.

So, How to export all the settings I've changed ?

Like folder settings, firewall settings, indexing settings, systempropertiesadvanced settings, start menu settings, mouse settings, group policies, and so on... (basically everything from control panel)

Most of them are on the registry. I just need to know where.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings are in different locations in the Registry, but you could in principle export each as REG files, and concatenate them if you wish to make restoring settings easier.

For example,

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel
```

has settings for many frequently customized items, such as Mouse, Sounds etc.
However, **there is a risk that an incompatible or bad Registry file could require complete reinstallation of Windows**.

Another option is to use third-party customization tool, such as [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/), which can export its settings and import them later.

Perhaps a better question is why you need to "wipe" Windows frequently. It would be easier to restore from an image than to start over from scratch, unless you're a developer who has to document a complete installation.

Comment: Thank you. This key will help a lot. Which settings would ClassicShell export ? It's own settings or something related to windows ? Will I be dependent of the program ?. "Frequently" is 3 times a year. Image doesn't pass me the feeling of a clean OS, you know ? Paranoid maybe, but... Tought about it once or twice.

Comment: By the way, how did you manage to find that key ? How do I find the others ?

Comment: Two ways to find keys: 1. Use a search engine, e.g. Google. 2. Use a program that logs  changes made to the registry, e,g, RegShot: http://www.howtogeek.com/198679/how-to-use-regshot-to-monitor-your-registry/ .